# 1 out of 3 div with absolute position with css

Tags: html, css

My idea is to have a banner and underneath 3 div side by side, what I would like to do is that when I scroll down only the center and the right div move.

```css
#banner  {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  position: fixed;
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  border-style: dotted;
}
#left   {
  background:blue;
  color:white;
  position: fixed;
  top:300px;
  height:300px;
  width:150px;
  border-style: dotted;
  float:left;
}
#center   {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  top:300px;
  left:150px;
  height:700px;
  width:150px;
  border-style: dotted;
  float:left;
  z-index:-1;
}
#right   {
  background:red;
  color:white;
  top:300px;
  left:300px;
  height:300px;
  width:150px;
  border-style: dotted;
  float:left;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  banner
</div>
<div id="left">
  left
</div>
<div id="center">
  center
</div>
<div id="right">
  right
</div>
```

To my understanding I should use `position: absolute` or `fixed` on the left and banner div. If I do this I have to give all DIV left: and top: properties, and to make them fit together. I should also give them height: and width and z-index to to #center and #right. My concern is that this will not be display properly in different browsers, resolutions, etc. Is there an easier way to do it?
this is my failed attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/y71fqthf/1/
As you can see the boxes can be seen going under the banner on the top of it. This is something I wouldnt want.

Or is this in general a bad way to display a website?

Comment: I would add a container to the content DIV's and add a `relative` blank DIV at the left and top to avoid using the LEFT and TOP properties..

Comment: But my advice for you is to use some grid, like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) this will make it easier for you to make the site responsive

Comment: @miguelmpn I am using bootstrap and its working almost perfectly. For some reason in my IPhone it does not fill the whole screen. If you want post as answer use bootstrap and you will get credit.

Answer (score 0):

change some css property

```
 #banner  {
      background:blue;
      color:white;
      position: fixed;
      height:300px;
      width:500px;
      border-style: dotted;
    }
    #left   {
      background:blue;
      color:white;
      position: fixed;
      top:300px;
      height:300px;
      width:150px;
      border-style: dotted;
      float:left;
    }
    #center {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-style: dotted;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 700px;
    margin-left: 156px;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 8;
    }
    #right {
    background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-style: dotted;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y71fqthf/1/

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is a bootstrap example, I haven't tested it throughly because I'm at work and I had to do it as fast as possible, please tell us if you find any issues, I'll try to solve them..

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.header-inner {
    background-color: #fababa;
    position: relative;
}

.content .sidebar-right {
    margin-top: 150px;
    background-color: #a9a8a8;
    min-height: 5500px;
}
.container {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.sidebar-outer {
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: relative;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header fixed">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 header-inner" >
        <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height: 150px;">
          Here goes the Fixed header
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 sidebar-outer" >
            <div class="fixed col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
                <img class="img-responsive"
                     src="http://placekitten.com/300/200"/>
                Here goes the Fixed column
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 sidebar-right">Content goes here (you can use sub-columns)...</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```